# laggy pygame run on pycharm on windows 10

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to learn pygame. I have a simple code and I am trying to move one of the spaceships however when I run it it is very laggy and inconsistent. I tried changing the fps rates and it seems to have no affect on the lag at all.

```
import os
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

FPS = 60
SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT = 55, 40
YELLOW_SPACESHIP_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Assets', 'spaceship_yellow.png'))
YELLOW_SPACESHIP = pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.transform.scale(
    YELLOW_SPACESHIP_IMAGE, (SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)), 90)
RED_SPACESHIP_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Assets', 'spaceship_red.png'))
RED_SPACESHIP = pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.transform.scale(
    RED_SPACESHIP_IMAGE, (SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)), 270)


def draw_window(red, yellow):
    WIN.fill(WHITE)
    WIN.blit(YELLOW_SPACESHIP, (yellow.x, yellow.y))
    WIN.blit(RED_SPACESHIP, (red.x, red.y))
    pygame.display.update()


def main():
    red = pygame.Rect(int(WIDTH*2/3), int(HEIGHT/2), SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)
    yellow = pygame.Rect(int(WIDTH/3), int(HEIGHT/2), SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
            draw_window(red, yellow)
            yellow.x += 1
    pygame.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong indentation: Your `draw_window` and `yellow.x+=1` happen inside your event loops. This means that the amount of movements depends on the amount of Events happening in a frame. Just dedent them once:

```
def main():
    red = pygame.Rect(int(WIDTH*2/3), int(HEIGHT/2), SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)
    yellow = pygame.Rect(int(WIDTH/3), int(HEIGHT/2), SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
        draw_window(red, yellow)
        yellow.x += 1
    pygame.quit()
```

Also, you probably should call `convert` (or `convert_alpha`) on the loaded images.

Comment: Thank you very much! the indentation fixed it. What is the usage of convert_alpha?